# Why does brush have only 3 hexa value?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, brush

For example, in [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there is code such as:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />
```

Why does the color property only have 3 hex value? Doesn't [color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.color.aspx) normally have 6 or 8 hex value? (like Fill="#FF0000FF") What does the 3 hexes means? mean?

Comment: `FF0000FF` is 8 digits long, not 6.

Comment: @BoltClock you're right.. it's an embarrassing mistake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brush colors may be specified in hex notation with three, four, six or eight digits as shown [in the MSDN page for `SolidColorBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx):

```
<object property="#rgb"/>
- or -
<object property="#argb"/>
- or -
<object property="#rrggbb"/>
- or -
<object property="#aarrggbb"/>
```

`#rgb` expands to `#rrggbb` (like it does in CSS hex notation), and `#argb` expands to `#aarrggbb`. Using three or six digits, the alpha is always maxed out. That is, these are all equivalent:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#FAAA" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAAAAA" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#FFAAAAAA" />
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you should be able to use all these notations with any other XAML attribute that takes a `Color`.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a 3 digit value, each digit is automatically doubled, so `#AAA` is equivalent to `#AAAAAA` and `#123` = `#112233`

Answer (score 0):

Your example FF0000FF represents 4 Hex (tuple) values which represent 4 Bytes (RGBA).
The term #AAA is a shortvalue term. #AAA equals #AAAAAA equals #FFAAAA